# Facebook's NativeAdsManager gives always the same ad

Tags: android, ads, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I'm using Facebook's NativeAdManager for Android as intended:

```
nativeAdsManager = new NativeAdsManager(context, "my_placement_id", 3);
```

which should load me 3 different ads, and them allow me to get them in my adapter using:

```
NativeAd adItem = nativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd();
```

but for some reason I always get the same ad. According to their reference:

```
The NativeAdsManager provides a mechanism to fetch a set of NativeAds and then use them within your application. The recommended usage is to call nextNativeAd() at the moment when you are about to render an ad. The NativeAdsManager can hold at most 10 unique ads at once but supports giving out as many ads as needed by cloning over the set of NativeAds it got back from the server which can be useful for feed scenarios.
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Build a release apk and try with it :)

Comment: No luck. I always get the same ad..

Comment: did you get fix? facing same issue.